# Ajustar columnas .csv con Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Tengo un problema, Python por default cuando me genera el archivo .csv me pone toda la data en una sola columna separado por comas, en vez de cada dato en una columna distinta. Necesito que los items creados se generen por default en sus respectivas columnas, pero no pude lograrlo. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar??

Acá dejo el código de mi Spider y abajo una captura de como se me genera el archivo .csv

spider.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from verbos.items import MercadoItem

class MercadoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'verbos'
allowed_domain = ['www.pt.bab.la']
print("Ingrese un verbo:")
variable = input()
start_urls = ['https://pt.bab.la/verbo/portugues/' + variable]


def parse(self,response):

    yield MercadoItem(
        eu=response.xpath('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()').extract(),
        voce=response.xpath('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/text()').extract(),
        nos=response.xpath('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/text()').extract(),
        voces=response.xpath('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/text()').extract(),

    )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Agrego Pipelines.py:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
import csv

class MercadoPipeline(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.files = {}

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    pipeline = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    return pipeline

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    file = open('%s_items.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')
    self.files[spider] = file
    self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file, encoding='cp1252')
    self.exporter.fields_to_export = ['eu', 'voce', 'nos', 'voces']
    self.exporter.start_exporting()

def spider_closed(self, spider):
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
    file = self.files.pop(spider)
    file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
    return item
```

Items.py:

```
import scrapy


class MercadoItem(scrapy.Item):
eu = scrapy.Field()
voce = scrapy.Field()
nos = scrapy.Field()
voces = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: No has copiado el código con el cual generas el `csv` pero me arriesgo a decirte que el problema no está en el código Python sino en el Excel, o más bien en la configuración regional. Es posible que la coma no este siendo considerada como separadora de columnas y se este usando algún otro caracter como `;`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ya agregué el codigo del pipeline.py. A eso que te refieres, ya hice lo de poner la coma en la configuración regional, pero no me cambió en nada, el Excel sigue mostrandolo igual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu codigo de scrapy.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from verbos.items import MercadoItem

class MercadoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'verbos'
    allowed_domain = ['www.pt.bab.la']
    print("Ingrese un verbo:")
    variable = input()
    start_urls = ['https://pt.bab.la/verbo/portugues/' + variable]


    def parse(self,response):
        ml_item = MercadoItem()


        ml_item['eu'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()').extract_first(),
        ml_item['voce'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/text()').extract_first(),
        ml_item['nos'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/text()').extract_first(),
        ml_item['voces'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/text()').extract_first()
        yield ml_item
```

En el yield le solicitabas todo en conjunto, con esta modificación cada dato se solicita como una lista y con el extract_first() sacamos el primer dato de la lista

Solo para verificar que tu archivo settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'verbos.pipelines.MercadoPipeline': 500}
```

[image: Verificación]

Comment: buenas, hice el cambio que mencionas pero me sigue figurando todo adentro de 1 solo campo, no me lo divide como en la imagen que me mostras vos

Comment: con que comando ejecutas tu spider? tal vez eso tenga que ver tambien

Comment: scrapy crawl verbos -t csv

Comment: si, igual que yo. Es raro que a vos te funcione y a mi no. Sera alguna configuracion del Excel?

Comment: ya pude! solo tenia que configurar en Region, un delimitador de listas y ponerle la coma, y al delimitador decimal cambiarle la coma por un punto (asi el de listas me toma la coma). Te agradezco muchisimo! me has dado con la solucion!! :D

Comment: añado una consulta, puedo hacer que me vaya juntando mas registros abajo de las 4 columnas? por ejemplo que para la columna "eu" me quede: "como" "comia" "comí" "comería" (uno abajo del otro, como si fueran distintos registros)

Comment: Solo conozco que se puede agregar hacia la derecha y posteriormente agregar nuevas consultas hacia abajo

Answer (score 0):

Casi 100% seguro que el problema es el Excel. Intenta ir a `Datos > Obtener datos > Desde un archivo > Desde el texto / CSV`, elige tu CSV y le das a `Cargar`.

Comment: si, es que si hago eso en el Excel lo veo bien, el problema es que necesitaria que cuando creo el .csv con el spider, me genere los datos ya divididos en las columnas correspondientes y no tener que hacer eso todo el tiempo, porque tengo que armar una base de datos con mi spider y si no logro eso no podre hacerlo